# What is a minimum ceiling height for a home gym?

Tags: gym, home-exercise

My house has a cellar about 4.5x3m 15' X 10') it's quite dry anyway but we're in the process of converting it.

We have a few options for the space but a gym would be great... Except the ceiling is only 2m (6'6") at the most. My wife and I are both under 5'7" but I wonder sitting or getting onto a bike/cross-trainer is going to be an issue. Clearly lifting above your head is out of the question but I'd be inclined towards a multigym anyway. No star jumps either.

Is this feasible? What ceiling height is a reasonable minimum of we don't mind some compromises, but are not prepared to rush banging our heads?

Comment: You can lift above your head while being seated. That shouldn't be an issue. I don't get what you are looking for, a list of all possible things you can do with a 2m ceiling?

Comment: You can though that's a different exercise... Though not important for me. I'm mainly worried a multi gym might be too tall or that climbing onto a bike, etc, you'd hit your head... Or find it's very claustrophobic having your head 1" from the ceiling

Comment: According to the cscs certification test, 12-14 feet for equipment clearance is the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

As much as you can I would recommend trying to basically do your workout in the space and then decide. You can't know until you try. As you say it could be a problem mounting an exercise bike or a treadmill because you basically have to assume a foot of headroom as well as if you do any bobbing when you run. One thing to also keep in mind is ventilation and what the room is going to smell like and feel like.

Generally though just make sure you can do any motion you would want to do. Jumps, overhead lifts and pull ups are really the height specific exercises so go into the space and try them.

Answer (score 0):

For commercial gyms ceiling height should not be less than 14 Ft and for home gyms ceilings need to be high enough for gym equipment and whatever you might be doing on it (i.e. running or jumping). A minimum of  8’ is highly recommended.